# How the model relations are working in this context?

Tags: laravel

I need to create an array where is necessary to store info about a specific registration in a conference. Is necessary to store:

- the conference name
- the registration type name and price
- also in the array is necessary to store the quantity of each registration type for a specific registration. The quantity can be getted using the the participants table because the structure of the participants table is like: participants table: id, registration_id, registration_type_id. So is possible to count for a specific registration_id how many registration_type_id exist for that registration.

So is necessary to do a query involving 3 tables registration, conference and participants, so the query should be like below and the order is "conference.registrationTypes.participants" because of the model relations right?

```
    $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('conference.registrationTypes
    .participants')->find($registrationID);
```

Then this foreach below stores in `$type_counts` the quantity of each registration type, and it works `$type_counts` shows:

```
 array:2 [▼
      "general" => 2
      "plus" => 1
    ]
```

Code:

```
  $type_counts = [];
    foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
        $name = $p->registration_type->name;
        if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
            $type_counts[$name] = 0;
        }
        $type_counts[$name]++;
    }
```

But Im not understanding how $type_counts shows that, how the relationships are working to get that result because `dd($registrationTypeDetails)` shows like below.

The `$registrationTypeDetails->participants` shows like below, the relations is empty so I dont understand how "`$p->registration_type->name`" shows the registration type name.

```
Collection {#335 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Participant {#350 ▼
      #relations: []
    }
    1 => Participant {#343 ▼
      #relations: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Do you understand how "`$name = $p->registration_type->name;`" in the foreach gets the correct registration type name?

Also `$registrationTypeDetails` shows:

```
Registration {#334 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "conference" => Conference {#342 ▼
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "registrationTypes" => Collection {#346 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => RegistrationType {#349 ▼
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "participants" => Collection {#514 ▶}
              ]
            }
            1 => RegistrationType {#351 ▼
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "participants" => Collection {#348 ▶}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Install `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` and check what queries were executed. It's good point to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observe that the calling `$registrationTypeDetails->participants` retrieves the participants relations to `Registration` (This is not eagerloaded)

When you called:

```
Registration::with('conference.registrationTypes.participants')->find($registrationID);
```

It retrieve a single record of `Registration` using the `registrationId` with eager-loaded relations. But when you use the following `$registrationTypeDetails->participants` You're making a fresh query using the record hence why you have `participants` model collections which you can run a loop on.

It works because you've already defined a relationship between the `Registration` and `Participant` (There's limited chance that this is wrong).

Because you didn't eager-load the `participants` relation(s) when you did `$registrationTypeDetails->participants` you don't expect it to show you the relations. Even though as you noticed `dd($registrationTypeDetails)` shows you the result of your first eager-loaded query.

The same effect is seen when you did while looping called `$p->registration_type->name;` This also runs a fresh query using the single record at the point of the loop (this record has both property of say `registration_type_id` that references `registration_type` relation on `participants` table...and so on...

In summary, this is the explanation of why you could access the related models as collections without using `with()` or `load()` methods.